# aiomysql connect error

Tags: python, sql

Всем доброго времени суток! Помогите разобраться. PHP с помощью localhost подключается к бд, а python код не хочет. Использую библиотеку aiomysql. Сам код:

```
import asyncio
import aiomysql

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

async def test():
    con = aiomysql.connect(host = 'localhost', port = 3306, user = 'user', password = '123', db = 'test', loop = loop)

    con.close()

loop.run_until_complete(test())
```

И вот сама ошибка:

> (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost'")

Не могу понять в чем проблема. PHP работает нормально под теми же данными, что использует Python.

Интересно то, что по внешнему IP, вместо localhost, Python создает соединение. Скрипт запускается на одном сервере где и MySQL и PHP.

Кто может помочь? Не хочу терять время на внешнее подключение к бд.

Comment: А если вместо `localhost` написать '127.0.0.1'?